# How to slide a component in a flatlist in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

The aim is to slide a component from a flatlist, to slide from right or left to bring up options like we have on Instagram. **Instagram has the slider report functionality only for iOS not for android**
[image: Instagram has the slider report functionality only for iOS not for android]

We already tried using react-native-navigation-drawer, as it can create menu inside of particular view, but it conflicts with our dependencies on project, so we are looking for other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `react-native-gesture-handler`

Example

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Animated, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { RectButton } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";

class AppleStyleSwipeableRow extends Component {
  renderLeftActions = (progress, dragX) => {
    const trans = dragX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 50, 100, 101],
      outputRange: [-20, 0, 0, 1],
    });
    return (
      <RectButton style={styles.leftAction} onPress={this.close}>
        <Animated.Text
          style={[
            styles.actionText,
            {
              transform: [{ translateX: trans }],
            },
          ]}>
          Archive
        </Animated.Text>
      </RectButton>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Swipeable
        renderLeftActions={this.renderLeftActions}>
        <Text>
           "hello"
         </Text>
      </Swipeable>
    );
  }
}
```